# Make radio button bigger?

Tags: html, css, button, radio-button

Is there any way to make a radio button bigger using CSS?

If not, how else can I do it?

Comment: see this link may be its help you http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? May be there is an alternative solution to this.... Like emulating Radio Button using Images....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727255/how-can-i-make-an-html-radiobutton-with-a-big-target-area

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Question, you have linked, has nothing to do with this OP's question. Here, bigger radio buttons are asked (solution is to change styles of `input` element), while in your linked question OP asks about bigger "clickable" areas (solution is to change `label` styles). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4920348/1469208), on contrary, are answers that suits OP's question asked in this question. Quickest answer ((c) [imanabidi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/184572/imanabidi)) -- "set both width and height and use em metric like : width: 1.2em; height: 1.2em".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920281/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-radio-button-using-css

Answer (score 115):

Try this code:

```css
 input[type='radio'] { 
     transform: scale(2); 
 }
```

Comment: Radiobutton looks better with "transform" than using "width" and "height" and it's much simpler than the other solutions.

Comment: It actually does not look that bad to me. I tested on IE 11, Chrome and FF and they looked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can easily able to set it's height and width as with any element.

Here is the fiddle with code

[**JSFIDDLE BIG RADIO BUTTON**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9bAe/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input id="r1" type="radio" name="group1" class="radio1" />
<label for="r1">label 1 text</label>
<input id="r2" type="radio" name="group1" class="radio2" />
<label for="r2">label 2 text</label>
<input id="r3" type="radio" name="group1" class="radio3" />
<label for="r3">label 3 text</label>
<input id="r4" type="radio" name="group1" class="radio4" />
<label for="r4">label 4 text</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=radio] + label::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #ffa;
}

.radio1 + label::before {
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.5em;
}

.radio2 + label::before {
    width: 0.75em;
    height: 0.75em;
}

.radio3 + label::before {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}

.radio4 + label::before {
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
}
```

Styling radio button is not easy.

Form elements in general are either problematic or impossible to style using `CSS alone`.

Just go through this link for your own style with bigger size for radio buttons..

Also look at this link...

[**Bigger radio buttons**](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/radio-button/)

Comment: This is pretty clever, I like it! Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @LukeP : Always WELCOME :)

Comment: Would there be any way to avoid hurting usability? Apparently this doesn't work with keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `transform: scale(1.3)`, it really looks horrible. Just use this:

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio">Select this item
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using CSS but browser and OS also impact on this. Look at following article.

[Styling radio buttons with CSS](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/radio-button/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" value="1">
   <div></div>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"] {
   display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + div {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   vertical-align: middle;
   background: #FFF;
   border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
   border-radius: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"] + div:hover {
    border-color: #c2c2c2;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + div {
    background:gray;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nuzhysgg/**

Comment: Label (inline element) can't contain a DIV (block-level element) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609554/is-div-inside-label-block-correct

Answer (score 0):

There might be some quirky `<span>` tricks inside radio elements but I imagine using them across different browsers would be annoying to debug.

I've used [this script](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) in the past but not recently.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 transform scale is blurry. Setting height & width does not work with FF (even the newest 66 does not support, 2020). The only cross-browser solution is custom HTML markup + CSS, which unfortunatelly is not the easiest way. See helpful tutorial [custom radios & checkboxes](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp).