# Increase radiobutton size - Chrome issue

Tags: html, css, transform

Hello! I am trying to increase size of radio button using the below css, which works in mozilla but not in chrome.

```
.rdo
{
margin: 1em 1em 1em 0;
transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
-moz-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
-ms-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
-o-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}


<input type="radio" class="rdo"/>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5x3ce/1/)

Any Solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the size of the radio button using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920281/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-radio-button-using-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920281/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-radio-button-using-css

Comment: lol @mplungjan we answered at the same time.

Comment: The fiddle works fine in both browsers here. For reference, add a normal radio button too and look at the relative sizes.

Comment: And I don't believe this is a duplicate. The other question asks: how can I style a radio button, and it didn't get an answer in 2011. This one asks: what is wrong with my transform property; the fact that it's about a radio button is a coincidence.

Comment: If you follow the links given, you will for example see this page which shows a large radio in Chrome but also shows how poorly it works in other browwsers: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/radio-button/

Comment: I don't think there is any way (certainly not *reliably*) to style radio or  checkbox `input`, or `select`, elements; [there are alternative approaches](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r6HeL/1/), though, which are reliable to an extent (though their suitability depends on the cross-browser requirements).

Answer (score 1):

Styling radiobuttons and other inputs isn't cross-browser. Each browser can render it in different way. I advise to use some methods of customizing inputs, like this: [link](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/)