# html - how to increase radio buttons size under Firefox,Opera,Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, radio-button

I want to keep default browsers appearances for all input elements 
I want only increase the size of the radio buttons (no jQuery,no bg image,etc) only
with simple CSS.

I use this simple CSS code:

```
.bigradio{ width: 2em; height: 2em;}
```

Which is working only under IE and Chrome, other major browsers (FF,Opera,Safari)
don't want to increasing default radio button size :(

Please help, I need a simple and clean CSS cross browser solution (no jQuery, no hiding default appearance, etc)

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the size of the radio button using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920281/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-radio-button-using-css)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/pKdr4/)**</kbd>

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio1" class="radio">Radio 1</label>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio2" class="radio">Radio 2</label>
<input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio"><label for="radio3" class="radio">Radio 3</label>
```

---

```
.radio {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio:before {
  background: #fff;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;

  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;

  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 0 #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 0 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 0 #ccc;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
} 
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2022";
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma; /* If you change font you must also change font-size & line-height */
  font-size: 44px;
  color: #00a0db;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px #bbb;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
input[type=radio] { 
transform: scale(3, 3); 
-moz-transform: scale(3, 3); 
-ms-transform: scale(3, 3); 
-webkit-transform: scale(3, 3); 
-o-transform: scale(3, 3); 
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDjHb/)

---

Keep in mind that this will scale the button without affecting the layout around it, i.e. nothing around it will move because of it, so use appropriate margins, paddings, etc.

Comment: under opera and safari its not working :( under firefox its solved the half problem only: the button is bigger but its very pixelate

Comment: on 1.2 doesn't seem so bad