# input-lg equivalent for checkboxes and radios

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a mobile-targeted page using Twitter Bootstrap. Since it's mobile-targeted, I'd like all my form UI elements to be nice and big.

The `input-lg` class achieves this nicely for ordinary text inputs. But it [has no effect](http://www.bootply.com/4yE2IHMhwx) on radio buttons or checkboxes, and I don't see an equivalent class for them mentioned in [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes).

[image]

How should I achieve the same result for checkboxes and radio buttons?

Comment: Not sure if its possible with CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920281/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-radio-button-using-css

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via CSS, you can add the class "form-control" to your checkbox or radio button and it will become bigger; input-* classes will not affect the size of the control, only with input-sm you can see a little difference.