# radio box checked on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check the radio box onClick using jQuery, my code is below:

```
<ul class="icons clearfix">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" value="123456" name="selecticon"/>
        <label for="select_icon">
            <img src="pics/123456.jpg" alt="123456" width="34" height="34" />
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" value="654321" name="selecticon" />
        <label for="select_icon">
            <img src="pics/654321.jpg" alt="654321" width="34" height="34" />
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and jQuery code...

```
//onclick select icon
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.icons li').click(function() {
    $('ul.icons li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected').children("input[@type=radio]").attr('checked');
   });
});
```

But on click its not checking radio button, please suggest, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
.attr('checked')
```

To:

```
.prop('checked', true)
```

You could also use `.attr('checked', 'checked')`, but it's suggested to use `prop()` for boolean attributes like `checked`.

You also need quotes around the attribute value here:

```
.children('input[@type="radio"]')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pUqBB/

Additionally (not related), The `for` attribute of a `<label>` must match the associated input's `id` rather than the `name`.

#### Most importantly:

You don't need javascript for this at all if you simply wrap the whole thing in a `<label>`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pUqBB/1/

See also: [How can I make an HTML radiobutton with a big target area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727255/how-can-i-make-an-html-radiobutton-with-a-big-target-area/7727390#7727390)

---

**EDIT**: OK, not sure if you're interested but I rewrote this with the accessible version using `<label>`, and js only to add/remove the `selected` class (since we *do* need javascript for that bit). I'm using this code in production on all my sites, feel free to use it (or point out improvements):

http://jsfiddle.net/pUqBB/2/

```
// Add class="selected" to the parent element of checked inputs

// on page load
$("input:checked").parent().addClass('selected');

$(":radio").live('change', function () {
   if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(':radio[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').parent().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    }
});

$(":checkbox").live('change', function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: firebug is saying '$(this).addClass("selected").children("input[@type=radio]").prop is not a function'

Comment: I saw a lot of other stuff that was amiss and edited my post, please have a look. You probably don't need javascript for this at all. What version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: You don't need the `@` in the attribute selector.

Comment: @Rocket: You're right but I don't think it's affecting anything (honestly I don't even know what it's for). You actually don't need jQuery or javascript for this in the first place so it's kind of a moot point.

Comment: @Madmartigan: True, well except he's setting the `selected` class, which would require JavaScript.

Comment: @Rocket: Oh yeah you're right, that part you do need js for. Probably better to bind `change` event to the input and add/remove the class from the parent label, but I'm outta gas on this topic for now.

Comment: @seoppc Try using attr instead of prop if you're getting the error prop is not a function. That worked for me. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3316879/620054

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on this line:

```
$(this).addClass('selected').children("input[@type=radio]").attr('checked');
```

First, you should quote your attribute selectors, and you don't need the `@` anymore.

```
.children("input[type='radio']")
```

Second `.attr('checked')` is a getter, it returns you the value of the attribute.  If you want to set it, you need to pass the value as the 2nd parameter.

```
.attr('checked', 'checked')
```

You can also use `.prop` which lets you use booleans instead of `'checked'`.

```
.prop('checked', true)
```

So, all together it should be:

```
$(this).addClass('selected').children("input[type='radio']").prop('checked', true);
```

**Note**: `<label>` tags are used to select input fields by their ID.  So, you can use them to toggle the radios.  Also, if radios have the same name, only one can be checked at a time.  So, add unique IDs to your radios, and set their labels `for` attributes to them.  Like so:

```
<input type="radio" value="123456" name="selecticon" id="selecticon_01"/>
<label for="selecticon_01">
    <img src="pics/123456.jpg" alt="123456" width="34" height="34" />
</label>
```

So, then you just need `$(this).addClass('selected')`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wQS46/

Comment: firebug is saying '$(this).addClass("selected").children("input[@type=radio]").prop is not a function'

Comment: @seoppc: Like I said, remove the `@`, and quote your attribute selectors.  `$(this).addClass("selected").children("input[type='radio']").prop`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).addClass('selected').children("input[@type=radio]").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vFCR/) is added.

Answer (score 0):

`.children` is not working.
`.find` should work.

```
<ul class="category-checklist form-no-clear">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="post_category" value="1" class="post-category">
            <span class="tag-name">Uncategorised</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="post_category" value="2" class="post-category">
            <span class="tag-name">Basic Statistics</span>
       </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="post_category" value="3" class="post-category">
            <span class="tag-name">Advanced Statistics</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>`

$('.category-checklist li').click(function() {
    $('.category-checklist li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected').find("input[type='radio']").prop('checked', true);
 });
```