# How to extend radio button clickable area to other elements using css or jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, radio-button

I have this html/smarty code for a radio button. I would like to extend the area for the selection of the radio button so that the user can more easily select it on [this](http://www.lolaartgallery.com/113-Just-Married-NYC.html) page? 
The classic trick of using label is insufficient here. All the actions performed when clicking the button must be performed, see the `onchange` parameters. I need to make a clickable zone including at least the whole table that contains this line, or even better: a zone that also contains the image above each radio button.

Is that possible in html, css, jquery?
Thanks

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <input value="{$id_attribute|intval}" class="{$groupName}"  type="radio" name="{$groupName}" id="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}" onchange="javascript:findCombination({$groupName});changeCombinationPrice();{if $groupName=='group_1'}getCheckedValue(document.forms['buy_block_form'].elements['group_1']);scaleImage('{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}','{$cover.id_image}.jpg');{else if $groupName=='group_2'}changeImage('{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}','{$cover.id_image}',{$id_attribute|intval}); {/if}" {if ($groupName=='group_1' and $countGroup1==1) } checked {/if} />
    </td>
    {assign var="hrup" value=$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'|lower}
    {if $feact==$hrup}
    <td width="17" valign="top">
    <script language="javascript" >
        Tooltips('{$feact},{$hrup}');   
    </script>  
    <div class="tooltip">
        <div class="toolimg"><img src="/pixelart/img/layout/corazon.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="tooldescrip">{l s="Finition recommandée par l'artiste"}
        </div>
    </div>
    {/if}
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="imputgroup_{$id_attribute|intval}">{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the clickable content in another tag (`A` is appropriate) and hook up the event handler to that tag. You'll also have to switch the radio buttons in JavaScript accordingly.

Comment: OK, I wrapped everything with a `a` link tag, and called a javascript function with `onclick` in this tag. The function I wrote selects the radio button OK, but it doesn't run the callings in the onchange of this radio button...how to do this? thanks

Comment: Do you find a cleaner solution?

Comment: You can call the radio button's event with jQuery's $(...).change(); You have to pass it a selector...probably something like $(this).find('{$groupName}').change()

Comment: Thanks @Diodeus. But I need to find the radio that has the class `{$groupName}` AND the value `{$id_attribute|intval}`. I tried this but doesn't work: `$(this).find('{$groupName}').('[value=={$id_attribute|intval}]').change()`

Comment: this would be better, wouldn't it: `<a href="Javascript:void()" id="radioClickAreaid{$id_attribute|intval}" onclick="radioClickArea(document.forms['buy_block_form'].elements['{$groupName}'], '{$id_attribute|intval}');$(this).find('.{$groupName}[value=&quot;{$id_attribute|intval}&quot;]').change()">`

Comment: It's better and cleaner to assign {$groupName} to a variable and hook up the event handlers at run-time and leave out all the inline code. This way you don't need to repeat it for every instance.

Comment: what does `hook up the event handlers at run-time` mean?

Comment: Using jQuery: $('.someClass').click(function() {...your code...} will hook up event handlers for ALL ".someClass" elements. No need to put on one every element in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

wrapped the area with a `a` tag:

```
<a href="Javascript:void()" id="radioClickAreaid{$id_attribute|intval}" onclick="radioClickArea(document.forms['buy_block_form'].elements['{$groupName}'], '{$id_attribute|intval}');javascript:findCombination({$groupName});changeCombinationPrice();{if $groupName=='group_1'}getCheckedValue(document.forms['buy_block_form'].elements['group_1']);scaleImage('{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}','{$cover.id_image}.jpg');{else if $groupName=='group_2'}changeImage('{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}','{$cover.id_image}',{$id_attribute|intval}); {/if}">
```

that has the same onclick parameters as the onchange from the radio button (not very elegant though!), and that calls a javascript function:

```
function radioClickArea(radioObj, id_attribute) {
    if(!radioObj)
    return;
    var radioLength = radioObj.length;
    if(radioLength == undefined) {
            radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == id_attribute.toString());
            return;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
            radioObj[i].checked = false;
            if(radioObj[i].value == id_attribute.toString()) {
                    radioObj[i].checked = true;
        }
    }   
    return false; // so that the link goes nowhere
}
```

The radio button gets selected OK.
Is there a way not to repeat the onchange/onclick parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Or like suggested here - use  tag surrounding your radiobutton or checkbox:
[How can I make an HTML radiobutton with a big target area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727255/how-can-i-make-an-html-radiobutton-with-a-big-target-area)